# How to add text area in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitextfield, uitextview

I am newbie for iPhone application. I want to add TextArea. I know how to add textField, however can someone help me how can I have Textare in my iPhone application?

I thought, I can increase the height of textfield and make it multi-line, however that option is not there.

Comment: Why can't you look through all standard components in IB? UITextView is not something hard to find.

Comment: @Flink : I have used `UITextView` many time, but I was under impression that `UITextView` is only for displaying text. `Editable` option did the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot increase the height of UITextField. for this you need to use UITextView.
In your Interface builder where you got UITextField, there is also an option of UITextView.
you can use UITextView same as UITextField in iPhone. UITextView is used for multiple lines

```
UITextView  *txt = [[UITextView  alloc]init];

//set frame

//add on view

[self.view addSubView:txt];

[txt release];
```

I hope this solves your problem [Sample Code for TextView](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_uitextview_uitextviewdelegate_2/)

Answer (score 3):

```
UITextView  *txt = [[UITextView  alloc]initwithframe:CGRectMake(x, y, width,height)];



[self.view addSubView:txt];

[txt release];
```

Comment: Please add some form of description as to how the code you posted addresses the problem. Also, you should place any code in your answers within code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this by clicking on `Mainstoryboard.storyboard` or `viewController.xib` and dragging in a `UITextView` This will allow multi-line text. If you need to access the Textview, type:

```
.h file

{
  IBOutlet UIITextView *textView;
}

 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView* textView;

.m file
@synthesize textView;
```

EDIT

to get the users data, hook up the outlet in storyboards,

then use:

```
-(void)getUserText{
NSLog@"%@", self.textView);


}
```

This should print out whatever the user entered into the textView.

Comment: Thanks. No one told me to click option `Behavior : Editable`. That will do the trick...